# Latitude and Longitude always getting zero (GPS and TimerTask)

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, gps, timertask

Below is the code I used for getting longitude and latitude within a timertask.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
if (isInternetPresent) {
try {
    gpt = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
    System.out.println("Internet is present");
    setContentView(R.layout.tracklayout);
    TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            Log.d("flow", "" + "task()");
            gpt = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
            lc = gpt.getLocation();
            if (gpt.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gpt.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gpt.getLongitude();
                Log.d("latitude", "" + latitude);
                Log.d("longitude", "" + longitude);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reached.. ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(myTask, 3000, 30000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"Mobile Data is Off","Please Turn On mobile data to proceed", false);
    }

}
});
```

Latitude and longitude are always getting zero even I manually entered co-ordinates through DDMS. There no problem with the code of GPSTracker. Outside timertask it worked fine. What is the problem with this code. Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

As you are using GPSTracker  ,If GPS is not working than you can not have lat and long values for sure, you can't get an accurate location. It may take few minutes or seconds because it depends on lot of constraints like yours position inside building, weather , you device hardware quality etc as you are using sattelite to have locations, So we can say thatit depends on the device and the environment settings ( weather, Location under the sky/inside or outside building,device hardware quality  etc as an example).

Why you are not using NETWORK_PROVIDER ?? if you can...
If you want to get a coarse location faster with program than you can get the location using NETWORK_PROVIDER, which isn't that accurate but can get you the location very faster.

Visit for examples

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: The GPSTracker class is that I got from androidhive.info. I used NETWORK_PROVIDER also. I am getting this problem while checking in the emulator. I send lat and longitude data through DDMS. I worked fine while it was out of the TimerTask

Comment: in emulator we can manually enter latitude and longitude through DDMS. It works always fine

Comment: yes that i know but i do not have extensive working experience with that

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timertask. Implement LocationListener with that activity. Write the codes in the timertask to OnLocation changed. Not needed to run in paricular time interval because we get the same data if we are in same location.